# Symbol not found: __ZTINSt3__112bad_weak_ptrE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, libgosu

I am starting of with Ruby game developing, as a beginner I am quite unsure about the properties of the gosu. While running `game.rb` I encountered the following problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from game.rb:1:in `<main>'
    2: from game.rb:1:in `require'
    1: from /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu.rb:25:in `require': dlopen(/Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: __ZTINSt3__112bad_weak_ptrE (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu.bundle
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
 in /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu.bundle - /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu.bundle
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We would also need to see your code. Thanks.

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` there? Looks like `gosu` native extensions were not compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem after updating my macOS to Mojave.

Reinstalling **Xcode Command Line Tools** solved it for me:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

xcode-select --install
```

Follow the pop-up instructions, restart terminal.